# Postgresql: how to set the date in all rows of table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `A` with field `duedate`.

I want to set all rows which `duedate` is less than today to be today+3 months.
for example:

```
id duedate
1   2015-08-15
2   2014-07-15
3   2015-03-01
4
5   2015-03-02
```

will be (today is: 2015-07-06):

```
id duedate
1   2015-08-15
2   2015-10-06
3   2015-10-06
4   2015-10-06
5   2015-10-06
```

Comment: You need to try it first, and post your SQL attempt.  It will help you get the most of this exercise.

Comment: UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE...

Comment: @sstan I know how to do basic set, I don't know how to make it work with dates.. especially when the duedate missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "today plus three month", simply add those three month to `current_date`:

```
update A
  set duedate = (current_date + interval '3' month)::date
where duedate < current_date
   or duedate is null;
```

The result of "date + interval" is a timestamp not a date, therefor this needs to be cast back to a date.

To handle the `null` values, just include an additional condition in the `where` clause. The comparison `where duedate < current_date` will fail for those rows where `duedate` is `null` but they will be included because of the additional condition.